# Select all data from two tables, group by items from first table (Basic SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, subquery

I have two tables ex:

**Classes**

```
| id | name | room |
|----|------|------|
| 0  | Math | 203  |
| 1  | Art  | 617  |
```

**Students**

```
| id | name    | class |
|----|---------|-------|
| 0  | Charlie | 0     |
| 1  | Bill    | 0     |
| 2  | Carly   | 1     |
```

Here's what I want the output to be:

```
[
  {
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Math",
  "room": 203,
  "students": [
     {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Charlie"
     },
     {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bill"
     },
   ]
 },
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Art",
  "room": 617,
  "students": [
     {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Carly"
     },
   ]
 },
]
```

I've tried `SELECT * FROM classes JOIN students ON classes.id = students.class`
But this obviously gives me all of the students in a row, with classes in each row as well.

Sorry for the basic question, I'm just not sure what to Google.

Comment: Are you using PHP here?

Comment: Yes, php. But ideally, it would all be in the query, right?

Comment: Ideally? We have very different ideas about what's 'ideal'!!!

Comment: What would be ideal to you in this scenario? @Strawberry

Comment: Incidentally, any column called 'id' is likely  to be an auto-incrementing PRIMARY KEY, so unlikely to ever be '0'.

Comment: I think issues of data display are best resolved in application code

Comment: So what would you do in this situation? Join the tables as I did at the end of my question, and then parse? The id column is a primary key but that is unrelated to the basis of the question. @Strawberry

Comment: I would join the tables, and parse the flat result in application code, as you suggest

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the input! @Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

I you want one row per class, with all corresponding students in a JSON array, you can use json aggregation functions and a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,
    (
        select json_arrayagg(json_object('id', s.id, 'name', s.name))
        from students s
        where s.class = c.id
    ) as students
from classes c
```

Comment: Thank you. This is just a basic example of what I'm requiring. In reality, the "students" table has additional columns. Is there a way to do this without listing all key value pairs in the json_object function? Ideally, I'd just like to get all values from both tables but format it in the way I listed above

Comment: @danthony: unfortunately, no. In MySQL, you need to enumerate the key/value pairs to create a json object.